# How to map data from API to CSV file?

Tags: python, api, csv

Im working on a take home project and i'm a little stuck on the last part of actually mapping the data from the provided csv file to the api response data i received.

The project involves writing a python script that uses an api to find project awards.
Using the CSV file provided, I need to map each project award from the API responses to the award winner within the csv file.

My python script has to output a CSV file with the original CSV file data plus the additional data provided via the API.

Here is what i have so far in two seperate files.

Im interviewing for a junior role so please be kind.

Thank you for your help!

```py
url = 'https://api.federalreporter.nih.gov/v1/Projects/search?query=query%3Dorgstate%3ANY%2CDE%2CMD%2CNJ%2CPA%2CCT%2CRI%2CMA%2CVT%2CNH%2CME%24fy%3A2019%24agency%3ANIH&offset=1'

r = requests.get(url)

print("Status code:", r.status_code)


response_dict = r.json()


res_dict = response_dict['items']
print("items returned:", len(res_dict)) #printing len or amount of items within this key


res_dict2 = res_dict[0]
print("\nKeys:", len(res_dict2))
for key in sorted(res_dict2.keys()):
    print(key)


print("\nSelected information about each project:")
for res_dict2 in res_dict: 
   print('Project number:', res_dict2['projectNumber'])
   print('Agency:', res_dict2['agency'])
   print('Title:', res_dict2['title'])
   print('Department:', res_dict2['department'])
   print("FY:", res_dict2['fy'])
   print('Total Cost Amount:', res_dict2['totalCostAmount'])
   print("State:", res_dict2['orgState'])
```

```
import csv

filename = 'legislators.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    header_row = next(reader) 
    lines = f.readlines() 
    print(header_row)

    for index, column_header in enumerate(header_row): 
        print(index, column_header)


    print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

use kaggle to get dataset ,join through API to google Colabratory.Google colab is the best platform for machine Learning other than IDE

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Can you elaborate a bit more on how to get the dataset? I know how to write all the data into a brand new csv but still learning how to map it to an existing one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).